# Index cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: arraylist, indexing

I get an error that the index over at `clientList.get(index);` can not be assigned to a variable. I have an Arraylist of clients that the index goes through and then it gets the clients index and gets another thing from another arraylist. I just don't understand why that index cannot be assigned to a variable.

```
public void billPrint() {


            for (int index = 0; index < clientList.size(); index++);
                Clients currentClient  = clientList.get(index);
                currentClient.getUnpaidBills();

                System.out.println();


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embrace your code with {} in the **for** logic.

You put a semicollon ; after your for what means "STOP HERE"

So just remove the ; after your for and put a { } like below

```
for (int index = 0; index < clientList.size(); index++){
    Clients currentClient  = clientList.get(index);
    currentClient.getUnpaidBills();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: OMG. I am really stupid. I need to rest I guess. Such a small thing. Thanks for the answer mate.